# Python: parsing a value(string) in a dictionary and replace it

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary, replace

my dictionary:

```
mydict{'a':'/1/2/3/4/5/wrong1', 'b':'/x/y/x/u/t/wrong2'}
```

I would like parse the value, and replace 'wrong*' with 'right'. 'Right' is always the same, whereas 'wrong' is different each time.

> 'wrong' looks e.g. like that: folder_x/folder_y/somelongfilename.gz
>
> 'right' looks like that: *-AAA/debug.out

so afterwards my dictionary should look like that:

```
mydict{'a':'/1/2/3/4/5/right', 'b':'/x/y/x/u/right'}
```

Just replacing the value won't work here because I want to parse the value and replace only the last part of it. It is important to keep the first part of the value.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `re.sub` to handle the replacement for you

```
>>> import re
>>> {k : re.sub('wrong', 'right', v) for k,v in mydict.items()}
{'b': '/x/y/x/u/t/right2',
 'a': '/1/2/3/4/5/right1'}
```

Comment: Even though I find it tricky to work with regex - this works. Thanks.

Comment: This works if the regex finds the pattern in all keys. I tried it on a dictionary, where not all the keys had the regex-pattern. This didn't work. I wonder whether something else was wrong with the dictionary... Anyhow. This is a very useful solution to my problem. Thanks